# emergency mode при запуске ubuntu 16.04. В чем проблема?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте! При запуске ubuntu возникла ошибка - выскочила emergency mode. Я запустил journalctl -xb | grep failed - оно мне выдало кучу всего. И в самом начале еще, перед emergency mode, писало:

Support for cores revisions 0x17 and 0x18 disabled by module param allhwsupport=0. Try b43.allhwsupport=1

Кто знает - в чем проблема, как это исправить?

Answer (score -1):

[Решил вот таким способом](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPqAVMYGFc8)

Вкратце - при запуске выбрать не Ubuntu, а Advanced Oprions - крайнюю версию Ubuntu generic